# AVAudioPlayer only plays 1 song in background

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I have a AVAudioPlayer that plays music and automatically goes to the next song when the current one is done. This works perfectly when the app is open, but when the app isn't open, it will only go the next song once. After playing one song beginning to end while in the background,

`- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag`

wont get called again. I have:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

in the viewdidload, But the problem still persiste, Does anyone know what would cause this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check Supporting Files -> YourProject-Info.plist -> `Required background modes`,
and Item `App plays audio` in that Key? It must be added to plist to play music in the background.

Comment: Yes, I do have that in my plist. I just got it working though, for some reason, setting the AVAudioPlayers delegate to the current view makes it work, even though I reuse the same audioplayer with each new song.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Here is another way, less bugs: This checks the current progress every half second (Could be less time for a more accurate song change). Just call one of the two selectors in your:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

Or in any other method, it is up to you.

```
-(void ) sel1 {

[self performSelector:@selector(sel2) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
NSLog(@"%f", ( _audioPlayer.duration -  _audioPlayer.currentTime) );


if (( _audioPlayer.duration - _audioPlayer.currentTime) < 0.5) {

    [self nextSong];
}

}

-(void) sel2 {

 [self performSelector:@selector(sel1) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.4];
}
```

----- //OLD WAY// -----

If there is anyone out there still trying to solve this I found this to be the best solution.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

float remaining = _audioPlayer.duration - _audioPlayer.currentTime;
[self performSelector:@selector(nextSong) withObject:nil afterDelay:remaining];

}
```

Just perform a selector after the app enters background. This will force the AVAudioPlayer to change song as soon as the current sound finishes. You have to be careful because every time the app enters background will set-up a new Selector, they will stack up (So it will call the selector multiple times at the same time). I solved this with a counter, always keeping it in 1. Like this:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
if (counter == 0) {
float remaining = _audioPlayer.duration - _audioPlayer.currentTime;
[self performSelector:@selector(nextSong) withObject:nil afterDelay:remaining];
counter ++;
}

}


-(void) nextSong {
counter = 0;

//Next Song Method

}
```